# create object same as vennCounts output directly

Tags: r, logic

vennCounts takes presence/absence data and produces this structure that is passed to vennDiagram to plot, e.g.

```
   t1 t2 t3 Counts
1  0  0  0      0
2  0  0  1     14
3  0  1  0      2
4  0  1  1      2
5  1  0  0      1
6  1  0  1      9
7  1  1  0      4
8  1  1  1      5
attr(,"class")
[1] "VennCounts"
```

If I know the Counts already, how can I create an object like this directly to pass to vennDiagram? In other words, how can I append the last two lines?

Comment: Perhaps, there exists a `as.VennCounts` function or something similar; also, see the `str` of a "VennCounts" object in case you're missing something while changing the `class`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the class of an object `x` with

```
class(x) <- "VennCounts"
```

There are no checks to make sure that your object conforms to the VennCounts class so you are responsible for making sure it has the exact same structure.